# Overlay a picture over background picture

Tags: java, image, swing, file, overlay

I'm making a street fighter game in java, I have all the background pictures finished, and I'm trying to add the characters onto the background, but in the output the character picture keeps appearing next to the background instead of on top of it. I want the character to appear on top of the background, just like a normal street fighter game.
[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

public class CastleFighter extends JFrame {
    Image image;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CastleFighter angela = new CastleFighter();
        angela.runIt();
    }
    public void runIt() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Castle Fighter");
        frame.setSize(500, 477);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel pa = new JPanel();
        JButton ba1 = new JButton("Start");
        ba1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.dispose();
                final JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Menu");
                frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
                JPanel pa2 = new JPanel();
                frame2.add(pa2);
                ImageIcon iii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("fight.gif"));
                JLabel imageLabel2 = new JLabel();
                imageLabel2.setIcon(iii);
                pa2.add(imageLabel2, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame2.setVisible(true);
                frame2.pack();
                frame2.requestFocus();
                imageLabel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 0));
                JButton ba2 = new JButton("How to play");
                ba2.setFont(new Font("Merriweather", Font.PLAIN, 28));
                imageLabel2.add(ba2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                ba2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        frame2.dispose();
                        final JFrame frame3 = new JFrame("How to play");
                        frame3.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
                        JPanel pa3 = new JPanel();
                        frame3.add(pa3);
                        JButton ba5 = new JButton("Return to menu");
                        ba5.setFont(new Font("Merriweather", Font.PLAIN, 28));
                        ba5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                frame3.dispose();
                                frame2.setVisible(true);
                            }
                        });
                        pa3.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                        pa3.add(ba5, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                        ImageIcon iiiii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("ezgif.com-crop-7.gif"));
                        JLabel imageLabel4 = new JLabel();
                        imageLabel4.setIcon(iiiii);
                        pa3.add(imageLabel4, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
                        frame3.setVisible(true);
                        frame3.pack();
                        frame3.requestFocus();
                    }
                });
                JButton ba3 = new JButton("Start game");
                ba3.setFont(new Font("RussoOne", Font.PLAIN, 28));
                imageLabel2.add(ba3, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                ba3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        frame2.dispose();
                        final JFrame frame4 = new JFrame("Level one");
                        frame4.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
                        JPanel pa4 = new JPanel();
                        frame4.add(pa4);
                        ImageIcon iiii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("ezgif.com-add-text-7.gif"));
                        JLabel imageLabel3 = new JLabel();
                        imageLabel3.setIcon(iiii);
                        pa4.add(imageLabel3, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
                        ImageIcon i14 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("fightercharacter.gif"));
                        JLabel imageLabel14 = new JLabel();
                        imageLabel14.setIcon(i14);
                        pa4.add(imageLabel14, java.awt.BorderLayout.NORTH);
                        JButton ba6 = new JButton("menu");
                        ba6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                frame4.dispose();
                                frame2.setVisible(true);
                            }
                        });
                        pa4.add(ba6);
                        JButton ba7 = new JButton("Level two");
                        ba7.setSize(400, 200);
                        pa4.add(ba7);
                        ba7.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                frame4.dispose();
                                final JFrame frame6 = new JFrame("Level two");
                                frame6.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
                                frame6.setVisible(true);
                                JPanel pa6 = new JPanel();
                                frame6.add(pa6);
                                ImageIcon iiiiiii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("ezgif.com-add-text-6.gif"));
                                JLabel imageLabel6 = new JLabel();
                                imageLabel6.setIcon(iiiiiii);
                                pa6.add(imageLabel6, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                                frame6.pack();
                                frame6.requestFocus();
                                JButton ba7 = new JButton("menu");
                                pa6.add(ba7, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                                ba7.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                        frame6.dispose();
                                        frame2.setVisible(true);
                                    }
                                });
                                JButton ba9 = new JButton("Level one");
                                pa6.add(ba9, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                                ba9.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                        frame6.dispose();
                                        frame4.setVisible(true);
                                    }
                                });
                                frame6.setVisible(true);
                                frame6.pack();
                                frame6.requestFocus();
                            }
                        });
                        frame4.setVisible(true);
                        frame4.pack();
                        frame4.requestFocus();
                    }
                });
                JButton ba4 = new JButton("Quit game");
                ba4.setFont(new Font("MerriWeather", Font.PLAIN, 28));
                imageLabel2.add(ba4, BorderLayout.WEST);
                ba4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
                frame2.requestFocus();
                ba2.setOpaque(false);
                ba2.setContentAreaFilled(false);
                ba2.setBorderPainted(false);
                ba2.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                ba3.setOpaque(false);
                ba3.setContentAreaFilled(false);
                ba3.setBorderPainted(false);
                ba3.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                ba4.setOpaque(false);
                ba4.setContentAreaFilled(false);
                ba4.setBorderPainted(false);
                ba4.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            }
        });
        ba1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        ba1.setFont(new Font("RussoOne", Font.PLAIN, 28));
        ba1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        ba1.setOpaque(true);
        frame.add(pa);
        pa.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        pa.add(ba1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("ezgif.com-add-text-2.gif"));
        JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel();
        imageLabel.setIcon(ii);
        pa.add(imageLabel, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.requestFocus();
    }

}
```

Comment: Swing components have a parent/child relationship. You need to add the "fighter" to the "background" not the frame.

Comment: How do I add it to the background? thanks

Comment: The code you posted has nothing to do with your question so you need to simplify the code by posting an [mre] demonstrating the problem. So you need to 1) create a JFrame 2) create your component with your background image and add the component to the frame. 3) create the component with your fighter image and set its size by using fighter.setSize( fighter.getPreferredSize() ) 4) add the fighter component to the background component. If you can't get this to work then you has simple code to post in the forum.